# Cannot boot into Windows 7 after Kubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu

Ive recently got this new system and have installed Windows and Kubuntu on it. It has an SSD and a normal HDD. I'm using the SSD for booting and HDD for file storage etc.

I installed Windows 7 first and once it installed I installed Kubuntu (as I always do) It usually detects the other OS and I rarely have any problems. But this time after I installed Kubuntu Windows could not be loaded or found. After a restart GRUB shows up but the Windows option is not present there, only Ubuntu is selectable.

I used Boot Repair but it did not solve my problem, here is the output of the boot-repair process: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12648497/

`sudo fdisk -l` output below

```
Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb78e143e

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 178456575 178454528 85.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       178456576 232243199  53786624 25.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       232243200 234440703   2197504    1G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xabdf2415

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *            63 1953127047 1953126985 931.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       1953127048 3906253447 1953126400 931.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       3906253448 5860533167 1954279720 931.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Output of `sudo update-grub` below:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sdb1
done
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: @L.D.James I've added the ``fdisk`` output to my original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the detailed repair link that you said you use.  While I'm sure they are important things to know and to study for when problems arise, I haven't ever had to use those details.  I'll study them later if you have problems with the easy steps that should work.

Just boot normal to Ubuntu.  Then run:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

This should update grub to include all the bootable partitions on all your detected drives in the boot menu.

If you don't see it as an option will you give us the output of:

```
$ egrep "^menuentry"  /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I don't know why I kept looking into extra tools when all I needed was this command. Even though it worked GRUB shows 2 windows installations, one on ``sda1`` and other on ``sdb1``. ``sdb`` is my HDD which has no Windows installations on it, while ``sda1`` is the correct device where windows was installed. Selecting either of the options takes me to the same Windows installation, none of them gives an error. Is this a matter of concern? Ive added the output of ``sudo update-grub`` to my original question. Thank you

Comment: @StuckInPhD Both your drive a and drive b are bootable and most likely point to the same location of your actually Windows installation.  If you actually had Windows physically installed in a different place, then you should have a menu option for each of those different physical location of the actual install.  The drive that you actually use for booting might not have the actually installation of your OS.  You could actually boot to a USB device that might not have an actually OS installation on it  The location might actually be your /dev/sda or /dev/sdb.  Glad it worked out!